# anynomyous function in fminsearch function

Tags: matlab, function, closures, anonymous-function, fminsearch

let us consider following code

```
function f = myfun(x,a)
f = x(1)^2 + a*x(2)^2;
a = 1.5; % define parameter first
x = fminsearch(@(x) myfun(x,a),[0,1])
```

i can't understand what is role of anonymous function in such case?because we have fixed a=1.5;why we can't insert directly?what is changed when we are adding anonymous function?i was reading several material,but could not understand completely role of antonymous function,for example in this case if a would be variable also,then it is clear that we are searching  minimum of function of two variable,but in reality it is function of one variable,therefore why we need this line?

```
 x = fminsearch(@(x) myfun(x,a),[0,1])
```

Comment: this is clearly explained in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/pass-extra-parameters.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/write-objective-function.html

Comment: yes i have read it,but what is idea mathematical or according optimization

Comment: The anonymous function is the objective function you are trying to minimize. If the function is parametrized (`a`), you create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) to capture that value from the parent scope. I must say, this is extensively covered in the documentation, so you might wanna read it again.